# как настроить много адресов в ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, dhcp, ipv6

Есть адреса локальные внутри сети `fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::/64` и глобальные `2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::/64`. При настройке обоих адресов

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf :

```
subnet6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::/64 {
  range6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555:: temporary;
}

subnet6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::/64 {
  range6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555:: temporary;
}
```

происходит ошибка, что интерфейс enp2s0 соответствует нескольким общим сетям. Почему вдруг сеть fd4a:: стала общей сетью, непонятно.

/var/log/syslog :

```
dhcpd: Interface enp2s0 matches multiple shared networks
```

Работает только если выдавать одну подсеть адресов. Как изменить настройки, чтобы выдавать много адресов разных видов?

---

*Причём, если оставить только одно локальное предложение `fd00:a000::`*

```
subnet6 fd00:a000::/64 {
        range6 fd00:a000:: temporary;
}
```

выдаёт оба адреса :

```
inet6 fd00:a000::dc42:4381:3c41:2bee/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 589984sec preferred_lft 71082sec
inet6 2a03:abcd:ef01:6666:dc42:4381:3c41:2bee/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 589984sec preferred_lft 71082sec
```

*Может и не стоит беспокоится по-этому? Так и должно быть?*

*Ubuntu Server 18.04*

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать имя "shared" вместо имени сетевого интерфейса в качестве общей сети:

```
interface enp2s0 {
  server-preference 255;
  send dhcp6.client-id 00:01:00:01:24:8c:1c:aa:bb:cc;
  send dhcp6.name-servers 2001:4860:4860::8888;
  send dhcp6.domain-search "domain.com";
  send dhcp6.server-id 01:52:54:00:1d:4f:78:9c:12:34:56:78:90;
  allow rapid-commit;
  shared-network shared;
}
```

Убедитесь, что вы используете правильный интерфейс и правильные адреса и диапазоны для своих сетей.

Comment: Не могу понять куда ваше объявление засунуть. Я просто обернул две эти сети в `shared-network ИМЯ { subnet6 .. subnet6 .. }` и сервер принял. Ваш ответ очень сложен к пониманию.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите выдавать разные адреса для локальных и глобальных сетей, вам нужно объединить их в одну общую сеть. Примерно так:

```
ubnet6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::/64 {
  range6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::1 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::ffff temporary;
}

subnet6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::/64 {
  range6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::1 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::ffff temporary;
}
```

Comment: ваше предложение по сути не отличается от моей попытки. А у меня происходит ошибка `Интерфейс enp2s0 соответствует нескольким общим сетям`. Почему вдруг сеть `fd4a::` стала общей сетью. непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось просто объединить эти адресные пространства в одном интерфейсе вместе, с помощью `shared-network` :

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf :

```
shared-network LOCAL1 {

subnet6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555::/64 {
  range6 fd4a:a058:d18c:5555:: temporary;
}

subnet6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555::/64 {
  range6 2a03:abcd:ef01:5555:: temporary;
}

}

# вторая сетевая плата

shared-network LOCAL2 {

# аналогично

}
```